# Remove auto generate button in Humberger menu of Xamarin.Forms Shell using Shell.FlyoutHeader

Tags: shell, xamarin

I have started learning Xamarin Forms Shell. I've create my first app using Shell and add sample Home Page. In my AppShell Page I've add  and Shell.FlyoutHeader contains only boxview. When I run the application and click the Humberger Menu, there is additional button or Label(I'm not sure) that I didn't include in my FlyoutHeader Page. Please help me to remove that additional button. Thanks!

Shell Code:

```
<Shell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="XamShell.Views.ListOfProductsPage"
             Visual="Material"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XamShell.Views"
             FlyoutBehavior="Flyout"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:XamShell.Controls"             
             Routing.Route="ProductList">

    <Shell.FlyoutHeader>
        <controls:FlyoutHeader/>
    </Shell.FlyoutHeader>

    <local:HomePage />
</Shell>

FlyoutHeader
<Grid BackgroundColor="White">
        <BoxView
               BackgroundColor="Yellow" 
               Opacity="0.6" />
        <Label Text="Animals" 
               TextColor="Red" 
               FontAttributes="Bold" 
               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
               VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zX2do.png)

Comment: Someone also want to achieve this. Please see link. https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/376133#Comment_376133. Thank you

Comment: please include a screenshot that illustrates the problem

Comment: @Jason Thanks for the comment kindly see this link. https://i.stack.imgur.com/zX2do.png  . I've not allow to upload image yet. Thanks

Comment: So you want to remove the buttons?

Comment: @BrunoCaceiro Yes! I want to customize my Flyout Items

Answer (score -1):

Do you want to achieve the result like following GIF.

[image]

If so, First of all, Please refer to this screenshot.

[image]

Please If you want to remove these button, please make sure your `AppShell.xaml` `AppShell.xaml.cs` file did not include the `FlyoutItem` and `<views:XXXPage IconImageSource="XXX.png" /><views:XXX IconImageSource="XXXX.png" />` like this link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/flyout#flyout-items

But I suggest you to create a new project.

Create a new shell file like following code.

MainPage.xaml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <Shell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SearchListDemo"
         xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:SearchListDemo.Controls"

   Navigating="OnNavigating"
   Navigated="OnNavigated"
   x:Class="SearchListDemo.MainPage">

<Shell.FlyoutHeader>
    <controls:FlyoutHeader/>
</Shell.FlyoutHeader>

<local:HomePage/>

</Shell>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
     [DesignTimeVisible(true)]
public partial class MainPage : Shell
{
    public Dictionary<string, Type> Routes { get { return routes; } }
    Dictionary<string, Type> routes = new Dictionary<string, Type>();
    public MainPage()
    {
       InitializeComponent();

        RegisterRoutes();


    }

    void RegisterRoutes()
    {
        routes.Add("homwpage", typeof(HomePage));


        foreach (var item in routes)
        {
            Routing.RegisterRoute(item.Key, item.Value);
        }
    }
    void OnNavigating(object sender, ShellNavigatingEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    void OnNavigated(object sender, ShellNavigatedEventArgs e)
    {
    }

}
```

regist `SetFlag` before `Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(e)` in the MainActivity.cs

`Xamarin.Forms.Forms.SetFlags("Shell_Experimental");`

Comment: Thanks for reply. I've try your code but the button is still there, it only remove the button name.

Comment: Did you re-create a new project to add my above code? Or you can upload your demo, I could help you to troubleshot this issue.

Comment: The user is wanting to remove the entire button in his original SO he didn't ask for the flyout menu